# Multiple line query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute multiple line query. I'm quite new to laravel.
Here is my example query.

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT

    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(`order` = ', `order`, ',data,NULL)) AS data', `order`)
  ) INTO @sql

FROM TableName;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  ID, ', @sql, ' 

                  FROM    TableName

                  GROUP   BY ID');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: [*# Raw Expressions*](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions) ...???

Comment: I tried that.. But since queries are multiple, so I tried both multiple raw expressions and single expression, but it doesn't work out form me! It was returning a null value.

Comment: Is the query returning any results if ran using any mysql client?

Comment: Yeah, I am getting perfect result after running on mysql workbench...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to dynamically converts columns into row, that's why I was using multiple queries. But then I manually write single query since there were only 4 unique entries in my order table, so it become more simple. Thanks for help..